# How to rehash executables in $PATH with bash

Tags: bash

The subject says it all, how to rehash the available executables available within one of the $PATHs after having changed things: e.g. removed a binary from one $PATH which is available in another $PATH, changed the $PATH-variable.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

`hash -r` is what needs to be done. In zsh it is rehash and rehash doesn't exist (by default) in bash.

Comment: rehash is also a cshell command.

Answer (score 13):

I use both shells and rehash has been reinforced in my hind-brain for decades, it comes out of my fingers without asking.  To accommodate those reflexes I have added `alias rehash='hash -r'` to my `.aliases_bash` file, which I test for and source from `.bashrc`.

To summarize, in `.bashrc` I use the line:

```
[[ -f ~/.aliases_bash ]] && . ~/.aliases_bash
```

and in `/.aliases_bash` I use the line

```
alias rehash='hash -r'
```