# MacOS cannot execute binary file after uninstall zsh

Tags: macos, bash, zsh, binary-files, macos-highsierra

After I open the terminal this text will appear:

```
Last login: Mon Mar 26 17:51:02 on ttys001
-bash: /usr/local/bin/dirname: cannot execute binary file
-bash: /usr/local/bin/dirname: cannot execute binary file
-bash: /usr/local/bin/tr: cannot execute binary file
-bash: /usr/local/bin/dirname: cannot execute binary file
-bash: /usr/local/bin/dirname: cannot execute binary file
Marek:~ marek$
```

This happens after uninstallation of zsh shell. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no MacOS X expert but I do know it's a BSD. I know installing packages on FreeBSD requires me to run `rehash` before it will find the new executables without an explicit path. Looks like in bash it would be `hash -r` so perhaps give that a try (see: [How to rehash executables in $PATH with bash](https://superuser.com/questions/490983/how-to-rehash-executables-in-path-with-bash))