# No such file error installing Oracle Instant Client

Tags: linux, bash, oracle-linux

I am trying to install Oracle Instant Client for Linux on Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS and I am getting this error when I attempt to run sqlplus:

> -bash: /home/ubuntu/instantclient_19_3/sqlplus: No such file or directory

First, I downloaded the following files:

- instantclient-basic-linux-19.3.0.0.0dbru.zip
- instantclient-sdk-linux-19.3.0.0.0dbru.zip
- instantclient-sqlplus-linux-19.3.0.0.0dbru.zip
- instantclient-tools-linux-19.3.0.0.0dbru.zip

Then I unzipped them into the folder `/home/ubuntu/instantclient_19_3/`

Then I installed `libaio`:

`sudo apt-get install libaio1 libaio-dev`

Then I exported the `$ORACLE_HOME`, `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `$$TNS_ADMIN` variables.

Then I added `$ORACLE HOME` to the path.

But for some reason the app is not executed. 
Full Terminal Output:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you `rehash` after changing the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked after rehashing the path:

```
sudo hash -r
```

Comment: We’re glad you solved your problem, but `sudo hash -r` doesn’t make any sense.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/490983/how-to-rehash-executables-in-path-with-bash

Comment: Yes, `hash -r` makes as much sense as a right glove.  And ``sudo hash -r`` makes as much sense as wearing a right glove on your left foot.